# Login attempt failed :: Authenticating Users on Force.com Sites

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I used this tutorial from https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Authenticating_Users_on_Force.com_Sites to create  a Login page in Visualforce with Username & Password fields and Buttons to have are: SAVE, CANCEL.

I have tried but login fails.
Showing error as:
Error:
**Your login attempt has failed. Make sure the username and password are correct.**

Here is the Visualforce markup for this page, in this case the source we are reviewing it is a component that is placed on the login page that you create within your site.

```
<apex:component controller="SiteLoginController" id="loginComponent">
    <apex:form id="loginForm" forceSSL="true">
        <apex:outputPanel layout="block">
            <apex:pageMessages id="error" />
            <apex:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-top:1em;">

                <apex:outputLabel value="{!$Label.site.username}" for="username" />
                <apex:inputText id="username" value="{!username}" />
                <apex:outputLabel value="{!$Label.site.password}" for="password" />
                <apex:inputSecret id="password" value="{!password}" />

                <br />
                <apex:commandButton action="{!login}"
                    value="{!$Label.site.login_button}" id="loginButton" />
                <br />
                <apex:panelGroup id="theLinks">

                    <apex:outputLink value="{!$Page.ForgotPassword}">
                        {!$Label.site.forgot_your_password_q}
                    </apex:outputLink>

                    <apex:outputText value=" | "        
                        rendered="{!$Site.RegistrationEnabled}" />
                    <apex:outputLink value="{!$Page.SiteRegister}"
                        rendered="{!$Site.RegistrationEnabled}">
                        {!$Label.site.new_user_q}
                    </apex:outputLink>

                </apex:panelGroup>
            </apex:panelGrid>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:form>
</apex:component>
```

**Apex Code for the controller, SiteLoginController:**

```
public class SiteLoginController {
    public String username {get; set;}
    public String password {get; set;}

    public PageReference login() {
        String startUrl = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('startURL');
        return Site.login(username, password, startUrl);
    }

       public SiteLoginController () {}

    public static testMethod void testSiteLoginController () {
        // Instantiate a new controller with all parameters in the page
        SiteLoginController controller = new SiteLoginController ();
        controller.username = 'test@salesforce.com';
        controller.password = '123456';

        System.assertEquals(controller.login(),null);                           
    }    
}
```